# why is ajax failing for partial data serialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this working:

```
jQuery( "input" ).on("blur", function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jQuery(this).closest("form").attr("action"),
        data: jQuery(this).closest("form").serialize()
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the above serializes the entire form, which I don't want.  I only want to pass the field that was changed.  By the way, I don't have access to the form, just the html.  Any help?  Could the form.php REQUIRE that all parameters are sent?  It is a framework I'm sending this to that processes all the database injections.  Any idea why the following won't work?

```
jQuery( "input" ).on("blur", function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jQuery(this).closest("form").attr("action"),
        data: jQuery(this).serialize()
    });
});
```

Comment: forms by default in action sends all fields on that form

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
jQuery( "input" ).on("blur", function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj[this.name] = this.value;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jQuery(this).closest("form").attr("action"),
        data: obj
    });
});
```

`serialize()` function is used for form submit, not just input. Then if you want to pass just current edited input, pass `name` and `value` as object to `data` parameter. jQuery will serialize data in object for you.

Comment: You should explain why this should be used and not just provide code.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, but this still didn't solve my issue.

When i look at the request / response in a proxy like fiddler, the first ajax block above gets a 302 back from the server, then a 200 afterwards.

When i look at the same type of behavior with the 2nd method I listed AND yours you wrote here as an answer, I only see a 200, with the data parameter passed, but the form never was submitted properly.

I have a strong conviction that this is the php itself.

Comment: Then php code requires all data to be submited. You have to edit there.

Comment: Another question:

Is:
    var obj = {};
    obj[this.name] = this.value;

THe same thing as
    var obj = this;

Comment: No, it is not. Check it by `console.log(this);`. `this` is more complex